# An epoch step is taking too much time on GPU!

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, dataset, cnn

I am trying to train a CNN on phoneme recognition. My dataset is composed up of 50 Million sample, each sample has 120 feature (signal parameters). My input's shape is (11,120) and the target is a phoneme class.

The CNN architecture is as follows:

- CONV (32 activation maps / ReLU activation) - POOL (max pooling)
- CONV (64 activation maps / ReLU activation) - POOL (max pooling)
- 3 DENSE layers (each contains 1024 neurons / ReLU activation function / dropout =0.5)

The output is a softmax layer for 36 class.

I used the f`it_generator` as I generate my data batch-by-batch. My batch size = 512. I tried to train the model on 10 Million of sample = almost 20K of batches however an epoch took me more than 3 hours.

The server i'm using has 2 GPUs:

[image]

Is that normal with such GPU characteristics? If yes, what can I do to accelerate my model training phase? Especially since I would like to train it on the whole dataset?

Comment: That seems very slow, my laptop should finish 20K batches within minutes. What software stack are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your response @Sebastiaan . In fact, i'm using tensorflow and keras, else i don't have advanced informations since i'm not the admin of the cluster.

Comment: Are you sure the model runs on GPU? or you are using GPU version of tensorflow and keras? because time I had same problem and later I realized that I am using CPU version not GPU.